# Plotting a histogram with custom breaks

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I have a vector like:

```
K <- rnorm(10000, mean=100)
```

I want to create a histogram of `K` with custom breaks (and labels) like `<20, 20-50, 50-75, 75-99, =100, >400`, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where by "self-defined breaks" you mean "custom breaks"? What @jbaums said, just use a custom `hist(..., breaks=...)` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `base` plotting, you might be better off `cut`ting the vector first, and then using `barplot` or the `plot` method for tables.

For example:

```
K <- rnorm(10000, mean=100, sd = 100)
K.cut <- cut(K, c(-Inf, 20, 50, 75, 100, 400, Inf))

plot(table(K.cut), xaxt='n', ylab='K')
axis(1, at=1:6, labels=c('< 20', '20-50', '50-75', '75-100', '100-400', '> 400'))
box(bty='L')
```

[image]

```
xax <- barplot(table(K.cut), xaxt='n')
axis(1, at=xax, labels=c('< 20', '20-50', '50-75', '75-100', '100-400', '> 400'))
box(bty='L')
```

[image]

Note that by default, `cut` includes the upper (but not the lower) bound in each bin, so for example the `20-50` bin includes any 50s, but the 20s will be included in the lower adjacent bin.

Answer (score 0):

Try ggplot version:

```
library(ggplot)
ggplot()+ geom_histogram(aes(K))
```

[image]

Many options are available for tweaking.

Comment: Using ggplot(), what is necessary here would be `scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(20,50,75,99,100,400))`.

Comment: I thought by "self-defined" breaks "like" <20,20-50,...  OP meant automatic breaks by code, else scale_x_continuous code can be added, as suggested by @jazzurro.